# jboss compatibility matrix?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

Is jboss-5.x compatible with java 7 ? Couldn't find any compatibility matrix of jboss version with java 7 on jboss site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JBoss EAP 5.1.2+**

JBoss EAP 5.1.2 requires a patch to work with Java 7. (Redhat recommends updating to 5.2 instead of the patch)

JBoss EAP 5.2 will work with Java 7. (No patch required)

[Source](https://community.jboss.org/message/846322#846322)

**JBoss AS 5**

No. This is going off the basis that JBoss EAP 5.1 (originally based off of JBoss AS 5.1.0 GA) and above did not work on Java 7 right away and required a update to resolve it. You could probably take a crack at trying to do it yourself but I wouldn't recommend it.

**JBoss AS 7**

From the [JBoss AS 7.1 Getting Started Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Getting+Started+Guide#GettingStartedGuide-Requirements):

> **Requirements**
>
> Java SE 6 or later (we recommend that you use the latest update available)
>   Java SE 7 can be used with JBoss AS 7

Comment: The current community version is `JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final` and the AS would of been tested with Java 7 for the documentation to say its ok to use. (I'd hope...) `JBoss AS 5.1.0 GA` may start up and work with Java 7 but it wouldn't be considered certified since Java 7 came out 2011-07-07 and that AS came out 2009-05-23 so it wouldn't of had whatever testing they setup run against it.